# Button's have limited PointerOver VisualState in NavigationView Header

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on my UWP project, and when I put a button in the NavigationView Header template, it only has PointerOver VisualState when the mouse is on the bottom 5 or so pixels as shown below. The dot represents where my mouse is on the button in the header.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v70Iq.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QQ5q.jpg

Below is my simple code.

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavigationView" Header="" SelectionChanged="{x:Bind mainViewModel.selectionChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAltHighAcrylicWindowBrush}">
        <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding listsClicked}">
                    <Button Content="Food"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

The same issue occurs if I put a CommandBar in the header. How can I allow the PointerOver VisualState for the whole field of the Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your pointer didn't move to the button, but was blocked by the title bar.

The relationship between them is like the one in the picture below.

[image: baa2eb5d-831d-4dbe-a3eb-67bf7f5ccd0b.png]

The reason for this is that you used

```cs
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

But the title bar is not **hidden**, it is **transparent**. It still stays where it is and is at the top of all the elements.

You have two ways to solve this problem.

1. Change your UI layout and move down the actionable elements (like buttons)
2. Use `Window.Current.SetTitleBar(ele)` to specify an element as the title bar so that it has the characteristics of the title bar while avoiding occlusion of the element.

Best regards.